# Can wp_die() first block, then continue page load

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I need to block and then revive the page? Note that I have to use the wp_die function.
If there is some alternating way to achieve this, please do tell.

Comment: What do you mean by revive? Are you outputting any text with your `wp_die()` function?

Comment: by revive? I mean I do not want to be blocked now.what i want is use wp_die() the do some operations and again open it(mean it should no longer be blocked)

Comment: If you have to use the `wp_die()` function then the only thing you can do is to put a link or something as an argument so people can reload the page for example.

Answer (score 1):

What you're attempting to do isn't possible.

When you run `wp_die()` some HTML is displayed before script execution is stopped. `wp_die()` ultimately calls PHP's `die()` function. Once you've killed the script there's nothing you can do to resume execution in the same request.

You *could* change the handler used for `wp_die()` but doing so would be to misunderstand the purpose of the function and wouldn't be recommended.

Further reading: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die
http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php